# How to use relative path in SSIS parameter?

Tags: ssis

I am working on an SSIS project and I use `parameters` so I don't have to change any path inside the package and when I run the project on my colleague's computer, they just need to change the path in `parameters`.

My project parameters look like this:
[image]

How can I use the relative path instead of using the absolute path like my example so my colleague doesn't have to change anything when running on their computer?

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing that will change in your Python path is the username, consider changing this to a variable with an expression:

```
"C:\\Users\\" + SUBSTRING( @[System::UserName], FINDSTRING(@[System::UserName],"\\",  1)+1 ,10) + "\\Anaconda3\\Python.exe"
```

If `@[System::UserName]` doesn't include a prefixed domain in your environment just use:

```
"C:\\Users\\" + @[System::UserName] + "\\Anaconda3\\Python.exe"
```

I'm not aware of any way to use Expressions in Parameters, only in Variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup **WorkingDirectory** using a full path, then your python will be execute inside the folder, it's like CDing to that folder in CMD.

1. So assign your `WorkingDirectory` to the absolute path of your project like: `C:\\User\etc`
2. Use combine of WorkingDirectory and relative folders to make the path for other part of your application like:
   `@[User::WorkingDirectory] + @[User::PathToTheFile]`
3. You can also deploy it as `SSISDB` to easily assign the variable using Project Parameters

[image: Working_directory_SSIS]